# How to use PandasAI with azure managed identity?

Tags: pandas, openapi, azure-managed-identity, azure-openai, pandasai

PandasAI framework doesn't have the option to use Azure-managed identity. Instead of using the Azure OpenAI API key directly, I want to use azure ad token in code. Is there any possible way toachieve this?

When calling OpenAI directly we use this code:

`token_provider = get_bearer_token_provider(DefaultAzureCredential(), "https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default")`

`client = AzureOpenAI(api_version="2024-02-15-  preview",azure_endpoint="https://{your_domain}.openai.azure.com/",azure_ad_token_provider=token_provider)`

Is there any provision for the same in PandasAI?

Comment: Just doing some reading.... PandasAI is a python library and does not include a REST API or authorisation. So if you want to access a PandasAI model via a secure REST API, you actually need to build that secure REST API, possibly inside an Azure Function or something like that. In comparison azure openai is a service that does include a REST API and authorisation.

Comment: Here is an example of building an API in Flask (Python) and authenticating to it using managed identity. In this example the back end service connects to a SQL DB whereas you will instead be doing your PandasAI magic https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-secure-python-flask-web-apis-with-azure-ad-14b46b8abf22